# Checking current server time in HAProxy?

Tags: configuration, haproxy, access-control-list

I try to define an ACL condition in HAProxy to check for the current server time and base on the specific time I will route traffic to certain backend servers.

But I don't find in HAProxy documentation on reading or extracting current date and time.

My goal is something like this in the frontend definition:

```
acl check_time_is_ls_12 "logic: check current timehour < 12 "
use_backend   back_server1 if check_time_is_lt_12
use_backend   back_server2 unless check_time_is_lt_12
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are after can be done using the haproxy runtime API, described here: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dynamic-configuration-haproxy-runtime-api/ and by cron jobs.

I am not aware of a simpler solution. Does that work for you?